# How to trim trailing spaces from char type columns

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

ASP.NET MVC Core 5 application uses Npgsql Entity Framework Core Data Provider to get data from Postgres database using Entity Framework Core.

Columns in database are defined as `CHAR(n)` type, like:

```
create table prpalk (
    sfirmanimi char(100)
);
```

Column types cannot be changed to varchar.

Using EF commands like:

```
string nimi = ctx.Prpalks.Single().Sfirmanimi;
```

to get data, strings in application contain also trailing spaces.

How to remove trailing spaces automatically ?
Is there some event in EF Core which can use to trim all string columns when returned to then application ?

I haven't found such setting in EF data provider, Npgsql or Postgres database.
Column types cannot be changed to varchar due to compatibility with existing code.

Comment: if you have such kind of need, you may also want a similar mechanism to (generally) transform all property values (mapped to some column), e.g: instead of trimming of the trailing space, you need to lowercase all ... So the general answer to this is just manually trim it, try to put the logic in one place so you can maintain it easily. Actually in DDD, this is part of the so-called business rule and usually placed in the aggregate root's methods.

Comment: There are large number of char columns. Adding `.TrimEnd()` everywhere makes code ugly. According to Sql spec trailing spaces in char columns are ignored. In server SQL commans this is done automatically. Maybe there is some event handler in EF Core which can handled to trim all columns in one place.

Comment: Ugly Code: The price paid for improper data typing.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using either `text` or `varchar` (with or without a size facet), which do not have this behavior.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately currently changing database column types is not an option due to compatibility with existing application. Maybe Dapper allows this. I posted realted question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770554/how-to-remove-trailing-spaces-and-change-encoding-in-charn-columns-in-dynamic